# Docker terminology confusion

Tags: docker

When we do,

```
docker images
```

I see a list of images with their repository, tag, image id, created and virtual size.
I understand what image id and created are.

But what is the relationship between repository and tag?
And is the virtual size?

I went through the glossary on their website. But I couldn't find any information about this. The reason I ask is because when I do `docker images` I sometimes see the same image being listed more than once with the same image id but different tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, I found it confusing as well.

In a nutshell:

- an image is uniquely defined by its id (a docker image is analogous to a git commit)
- a given image may be tagged one or multiple times (just like git tags)
- a repository is a set of images, to quote the documentation: "a repository is a hosted collection of tagged images that together create the file system for a container."

The git analogy might be useful to grasp this.

About the size: "size" is the size of the commit (eg: of the image), while virtual size is the cumulative size of all "previous" images this image is based upon (eg: "all previous commits"). Some info here: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/594 and https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/22

Does it help?

Comment: So basically a repository is a collection of images. And each individual image can be used to create the file system for a container..?

Comment: Any image may be used to start a container, right. Now, a container starts from a given image and all *parents images*, up to the base image (yet again, think about git - if you checkout, you get a working tree from applying all commits up to the checked-out commit).